# python3 annotation with subclass method

Tags: python-3.x, subclass, python-typing

When i use the subclass method, a method that base class don't have, comes the warning.
Code is as following:

```
class A:
    pass


class B(A):
    def b_method(self):
        pass


def test(arg: A):
    arg.b_method() #generate warning at this line
```

warning:Unresolved attribute reference 'b_method' for class 'A'

The variables of the input function can only be class A and its subclasses, and the function will call the unique method of some subclasses. How to write type annotations to eliminate the warning?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are seeing is expected.

A is the parent class
B is child class.

B can access a method that A has but not vice versa..

Makes sense?